# arel union and latest conversation from messages

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, arel

I need a list of messages where each one is the most recent in the "conversation" between the current user and each other user.

The same query is described [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4702688/i-could-use-some-help-with-my-sql-command)

The code I have so far is:

```
t1 = Arel::Table.new(:messages, :as => 't1')
t2 = Arel::Table.new(:messages, :as => 't2')

convs1 = t1.
          project(
                  t1[:receiver_user_id].as('other_user_id'), 
                  t1[:receiver_user_id].as('receiver_user_id'), 
                  t1[:sender_user_id].as('sender_user_id'), 
                  t1[:created_at].as('created_at')
                 ).
          where(t1[:sender_user_id].eq(user.id))

convs2 = t2.project(
                  t2[:sender_user_id].as('other_user_id'), 
                  t2[:receiver_user_id].as('receiver_user_id'), 
                  t2[:sender_user_id].as('sender_user_id'), 
                  t2[:created_at].as('created_at')
                 ).
          where(t2[:receiver_user_id].eq(user.id))

conv = convs1.union(convs2)
```

First off, I get an error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check \
  the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near \
  'UNION SELECT `t2`...
```

This works if I manually replace "UNION" with "UNION ALL" in the sql produced below.
conv.to_sql from the above code produces:

```
SELECT `t1`.`receiver_user_id` AS other_user_id, 
       `t1`.`receiver_user_id` AS receiver_user_id, `
        t1`.`sender_user_id` AS sender_user_id, 
       `t1`.`created_at` AS created_at 
  FROM `messages` `t1` 
 WHERE `t1`.`sender_user_id` = 50 
UNION 
SELECT `t2`.`sender_user_id` AS other_user_id, 
       `t2`.`receiver_user_id` AS receiver_user_id, 
       `t2`.`sender_user_id` AS sender_user_id, 
       `t2`.`created_at` AS created_at 
  FROM `messages` `t2` 
 WHERE `t2`.`receiver_user_id` = 50
```

Any idea why there's a MySQL UNION error. Is it an arel bug?
Secondly, any help with completing the query would be much appreciated.

**Update:**
Using Arel::Nodes::Union.new works

Comment: How to use Arel::Nodes::Union.new?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the code I used instead in the end

```
all_msgs = Message.where("messages.sender_user_id = ? OR messages.receiver_user_id = ?",
                                     user.id, user.id)

msg_ids = all_msgs.select("sender_user_id, receiver_user_id, max(id) as max_id")
.group(:sender_user_id, :receiver_user_id).map { |m| m.max_id }

all_msgs = all_msgs.where(:id => msg_ids)
```

Answer (score 3):

I think this is more probably a mysql fault, this is a mySQL error text. Something similar is discussed in [here](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=7684), but not exactly this issue.

Try to migrate to another sql server, and check again, or if `union all` works then use [this](http://rubydoc.info/gems/arel/2.0.9/Arel/Nodes/UnionAll):

```
conv = convs1.union(convs2, :all)
```

Based on documentation.

Comment: this is select_manager.rb, so it would be convs1.union(:all, convs2), but the UNION ALL is not actually the cause of the problem I realise now (see below)

Comment: Your sql code inlcuded int the question did not contained any parentheses. Anyway, parentheses can mess up the mysql somehow.

Comment: This is related to the parenthesis in Mysql query and not because of union or union all.
I'm getting the following query while using union method: `(Query1 UNION Query2)`.
This doesnt work in Mysql. But the following query works perfectly: `(Query1) UNION (Query2)`.
I don't know how to make it work using Arel.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is actually the parentheses in the sql. It works if I run:

```
Message.find_by_sql conv.to_sql.delete('()')
```

which removes the leading "(" and trailing ")"

Weird.. I don't know how I would chain this to complete the query. (Arel::Nodes::Union doesn't have a group method). This is Rails 3.1.4

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and solved it as follows:

```
  def last_messages
    Message.find_by_sql("
          SELECT  messages.*,
                  (IF(recipient_id = #{id}, 0,1)) as outlast,
                  users.avatar_name,
                  users.name 
          FROM messages 
          INNER JOIN users 
              ON users.id=(IF(recipient_id = #{id}, sender_id,recipient_id))
          WHERE messages.id IN 
              ( SELECT max(id)
                FROM messages
                WHERE recipient_id = #{id} OR sender_id = #{id}
                GROUP BY (IF(recipient_id = #{id}, sender_id, recipient_id))
              )
          ORDER BY messages.id DESC")
  end
```